# Changing the scale and dtype of an image in opencv

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I am reading an image and trying to change it's dtype to float32 and the values to the range `0-1`. Here is my code:

```
img = cv2.imread('sample.png')
fg = np.ones_like(img)*255
fg[(img >0).any(-1)] = 0
fg = cv2.convertScaleAbs(fg, 1.0/255.0, cv2.CV_32FC3)
```

But when I check the `dtype` and `min and max` of `fg`, it says `uint8` and `0 and 255`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try reading [the documentation of `convertScaleAbs`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#convertscaleabs)? I suppose not, since the first thing it says is "Scales, calculates absolute values, and **converts the result to 8-bit**." (emphasis mine) | Not to mention you're passing incorrect parameters -- `1.0/255.0` in place of destination, and whatever value the enum `cv2.CV_32FC3` has as alpha.

Comment: Okay I didn't notice that. Apologies. But then what's the equivalent of `convertTo` function which is available in C++ version?

Comment: You should rather convert to `float` using `fg = fg.astype(np.float32)`

Comment: Use numpy: `np.float32(fg / 255.0)` The division by a floating point value will give you a float64 result, then just cast it.

Comment: Yeah I know that I can use numpy but I was looking for the alternative to the `convertTo` option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `cv2.convertScaleAbs` you should replace it with:

```
fg = fg / 255.0
```

Now when you check the minimum and maximum values in `fg` they would be returned as follows:

```
np.min(fg)
Out[150]: 0.0

np.max(fg)
Out[151]: 0.0
```

#### UPDATE:

You can also try:

```
fg = np.float32(fg / 255)
```